# passing in expression as an argument in r

Tags: r, function, rlang

I'm struggling to understand the issues with passing in  arguments from a function into an R function.  I normally am able to get this to work just fine by doing !!rlang::sym(argument).

What I'm trying to do is create a function that lets me customize which column in a dataset I want to do a given comparison calculation count on.

For example, I might want to count the number of values equal to 9999 or greater than 5,  or maybe less than or equal to 5.  This column could change as well.

```
custom_count=function(dataset, expr){

  result=dataset %>% summarise( sum( !!rlang::sym(expr), na.rm = TRUE)) 
  return(result)
}

custom_count(mtcars, 'mpg > 10')
custom_count( mtcars, 'vs==0')
```

However, these don't work.  Is there anyway for me to pass in this combination of field + comparison sign+ value at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `enexpr` because you're passing an expression, not a symbol :

```
library(dplyr)
custom_count=function(dataset, expr){
  result=dataset %>% summarise( sum( !!rlang::enexpr(expr), na.rm = TRUE)) 
  return(result)
}

custom_count(mtcars, mpg > 10)
#   sum(mpg > 10, na.rm = TRUE)
# 1                          32
custom_count( mtcars, vs==0)
#   sum(vs == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
# 1                         18
```

Comment: @runningbirds To answer your question about using expressions specified as strings, replace `rlang::enexpr` with `rlang::parse_expr` in this answer. You should then be able to do `custom_count( mtcars, "mpg > 10" )`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.

```
custom_count=function(dataset, expr){      
  result=dataset %>% summarise( sum( !!expr, na.rm = TRUE)) 
  return(result)
}

custom_count(mtcars, quote(mpg > 10))
```

Comment: this is great, but what is the equivalent process for when I want to pass in the expr value as a string... "mpg > 10" instead of this way ?